# How to replace last comma by dot in comma-separated words from datatool's database?

Tags: punctuation, datatool

How to replace last comma by dot in comma-separated words from datatool's database? Can it be done ***without*** calculating the number of entries in the database?

```
% !TeX program = pdflatex                                   
% !TeX encoding = utf8


\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
Number|Entry
1|Alpha
2|Beta
3|Gamma
4|Delta
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLsetseparator{|}
\DTLloaddb{letters}{data.dat}

\begin{document}

\DTLforeach*{letters}% database label
{\Entry=Entry}% assignment
{% Stuff to do at each iteration:
            \Entry,
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\DTLiflastrow`:

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
Number|Entry
1|Alpha
2|Beta
3|Gamma
4|Delta
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLsetseparator{|}
\DTLloaddb{letters}{data.dat}

\begin{document}

\DTLforeach*{letters}% database label
{\Entry=Entry}% assignment
{% Stuff to do at each iteration:
     \DTLiflastrow{\Entry.}{\Entry,}       
}
\end{document}
```

[image]