# How to replace last comma by dot after last encountered word?

Tags: punctuation, datatool

My question is [related](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/487682/how-to-replace-last-comma-by-dot-in-comma-separated-words-from-datatools-databa/487686#487686) but with some complication.
How to replace last comma by dot after last ***encountered*** word?

```
% !TeX program = pdflatex                                   
% !TeX encoding = utf8


\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
Number|Entry
1|Alpha
2|Beta
2|Gamma
3|Delta
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLsetseparator{|}
\DTLloaddb{letters}{data.dat}

\begin{document}

\DTLforeach*[\Number=2]{letters}% database label
{\Number=Number, \Entry=Entry}% assignment
{% Stuff to do at each iteration:
            \DTLiflastrow{\Entry.}{\Entry,} % Here should be a right solution
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A solution is not difficult in this particular case where at each iteration you just add `\Entry`. I'm afraid you can have more complicated settings, so I'm waiting for you to be more specific. Or are all applications like this and the one in your previous question?

Comment: @egreg All applications like in my MWE, maybe, one possible complication, the entries can be located not only in a row but also in a column.

Answer (score 1):

The other way round:

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
Number|Entry
1|Alpha
2|Beta
2|Gamma
3|Delta
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLsetseparator{|}
\DTLloaddb{letters}{data.dat}

\begin{document}

\DTLforeach*[\Number=2]{letters}% database label
{\Number=Number, \Entry=Entry}% assignment
{\DTLiffirstrow{}{, }%
% Stuff to do at each iteration:
\Entry
}
\end{document}
```

[image]